# Ambiguity in "Illīus hominis fīlium laudābant omnēs"?

Tags: genitive, demonstrative-pronoun, demonstrative-adjective

Each question below assumes that any previous question has been answered with a yes.

1. Is *ille* ever used alone as *that* is used in this sentence?

   > **That** is a good idea.
2. Is *illīus* ever used alone as *of that* is in this sentence?

   > The idea **of that** alone was worth something.
3. Is there an ambiguity in this sentence?

   > **Illīus** hominis fīlium laudābant omnēs.

   I have in mind these two readings:

   > (a) All praised **that** man's son.
   >   (b) All praised the son of the man **of that**.

   By (a), *Illīus* qualifies (determines) and agrees with *hominis*.

   By (b), *Illīus* refers to an object other than *hominis*.  Maybe we have been referring to a woman as *illa*, who has married a man, who has a son by a former marriage, who was in general favor.

**BACKGROUND**

I am not asking whether any Latin speaker would have used the quoted sentence to mean (b).  I am only asking whether (b) could or could not be ruled out as a matter of grammar.  If I knew Latin better, I might have tried to come up with a more plausible (natural sounding) example.

What gave me the idea of (b) is the genitive forms of German personal or demonstrative pronouns, such as *seiner* for *er* or *deren* (*derer*) for *die*, as in:

> Wir wollen **seiner** gedenken.
>   Erinnert euch **derer**, die nicht mehr unter uns sind.

The German examples are from [this](http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-Pers.html?MenuId=Word420) and [this](http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-der-die-das.html?MenuId=Word4240&lang=en) Web page.

The Latin sentence is from page 124 of *Beginner's Latin Book* by William C. Collar and M. Grant Daniell (1887).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, the boundary between adjective and substantive nouns is often unclear in Latin and Greek. So adjectives can generally be used like substantive nouns, and demonstrative pronouns like *ille* are adjectival and can be used like substantive nouns as well. So *ille* can be "he" or whatever pronoun fits the antecedent. Similarly—or the other way around—, nouns like *amicus* and *senex* can also be used like adjectives: *senator amicus* "a befriended senator", *servus senex* "and old slave". Or "a friend who is a senator", "a servile old man": it makes no difference in Latin.
2. Yes, by all means, if the word that *illius* refers to (its antecedent) is inanimate in English, then you can translate it with "of that".
3. There is at least theoretical ambiguity, yes. It could be "the son of the man **of that/her/him**" (*illius* can be masculine, feminine, or neuter in Latin), or "the son of **that** man". However, I suspect *illius* would be read adjectivally in your example by 99% of readers, for "the man of that/her/him" is semantically unlikely. In other sentences, though, it can very well be used in the way you are looking for.

P.S. The genitive *eius* is routinely used to mean "of him/her/it, his/her/its", and so is *eorum/earum* "of them, their".

It may interest you to know that Latin does in fact use words that look like the genitives of possessive pronouns instead of the genitives of personal pronouns: *mei, tui, sui* should and can mean "of my, of your, of his/her/its (own)", from the possessive pronouns *meus, tuus, suus*; but they are in fact often used to mean "of me, of you, of him/her/it(self)", in constructions where the genitive does not indicate something possessed but rather something else (called the *genitivus obiectivus*). So *tuus amor mei* would mean, "your love of me", where I am the object of your love, and you the one who holds possesses this love (although I'm not sure whether the Romans would use both pronouns in the same nominal group).

This is fairly close to the German construction, which also used possessive pronouns, rather than demonstratives. Note that the German construction is to a limited extent also possible in Dutch. Cf. also English *a friend of mine*.

Maybe *mei* etc. aren't etymologically from *meus* etc.: I seem to remember that they might not be. But they do look like possessives.

Comment: If I recall correctly, *mei* etc. are from the possessive pronouns, supplanting earlier *mis, tis,* etc.